# How to position an element on a page when a shortcode is involved?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I developed a custom form (a cost estimator) on my site using a plugin. The form looks and works as it should but I need to add some text and a button underneath the right-side column of the form (please see image).

[image: desired position of element]

I used the ::after selector to get the text under the right side container, but how can I get  the button to follow it?

I tried using the ::before and ::after selector but it did not work (the text went above the container). I also looked at ways to chain 2 ::after selectors but this option will not allow me to create a clickable button anyway...

CSS:

```
.calc-subtotal-wrapper::after { 
    content: "The above calculation is for simulation purposes only";
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="button-holder-sim">
    <a href="#" class="button button-appt">Request Appointment</a>
</div>
```

Any suggestions to accomplish this will be very, very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the whole HTML and CSS? That will be helpful to understand the situation better.

Comment: That's part of the problem. I am using a shortcode generated by the plugin. I can see the HTML and CSS when I click Inspect in the dev tools in Chrome, but I cannot edit the HTML in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.button-holder-sim a {
  display: none;
}
.button-holder-sim:after {
  content: 'whatever needs to be displayed';
}
```

```html
<div class="button-holder-sim">
    <p style="font-style:italic">The above calculation is for simulation purposes only.</p>
    <a href="#" class="button button-appt">Request Appointment</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this snippet and the text goes under the left-side column. I would like it to go under the right-side (shorter) column as seen in the picture. Is there a way to do this through CSS? The 2 columns are in flexboxes